# "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType" after using Streamlit file_uploader

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit, openai-api

I am trying to use streamlit and gpt index to create some kind of a dummy test website. I keep getting the same error.

```
from gpt_index import GPTListIndex, readers, GPTSimpleVectorIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, download_loader
from langchain import OpenAI
import logging
import sys
import os
import streamlit as st

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = "I am deleting my api key from this post"



fileup = st.file_uploader(label=" ")


SimpleDirectoryReader = download_loader("SimpleDirectoryReader")
loader = SimpleDirectoryReader(fileup)
documents = loader.load_data()
index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex(documents)
index.save_to_disk('index.json')
question = st.text_input("What do you want me to do with the file uploaded?")
response = index.query(question)
st.write(response)
```

Why do I keep getting "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType"?

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "/app/indextest/streamlit_app.py", line 16, in <module>
    loader = SimpleDirectoryReader(fileup)
  File ".modules/file.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.input_dir = Path(input_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1082, in __new__
    self = cls._from_parts(args, init=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 707, in _from_parts
    drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 691, in _parse_args
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Streamlit documentation, `st.file_uploader` either returns `None` or an `UploadedFileObject` (which can be used as a "file-like" object):

https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader

It doesn't explicitly mention it, but presumably it returns `None` if no file was uploaded. We can't tell you why no file was uploaded.

In your case this means that the `fileup` variable is `None`, which is an invalid argument for `SimpleDirectoryReader`, as seen from the error message.

The example in the documentation includes an `if` statement to only continue in the script if the returned value is not `None`. You should probably do the same.

Comment: I put it all in an IF statement and now this is the error I am getting: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not UploadedFile